# Move Partitions For Space

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I'd like to increase the partition space on my Ubuntu. I've made an empty partition, but it is to the left of my Ubuntu. In between the free space and the Ubuntu partition is my 512 boot partition.[image: Partition]

I tried moving the boot partition to the left so I could increase the space, but I was warned by Ubuntu that the operation was not safe.

Can I safely increase my partition or just stay with what I have?

Comment: You will need to re-install grub after that.

Comment: @Pilot6 That just means have an Ubuntu flash drive ready?

Comment: You can't move partitions without using LiveUSB. After you move the `/` you will need to re-install grub. You can find directions how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot move a mounted partition, so you had to unmount /boot, move the partition (which in fact means copying the content tonother place), then remount /boot and reinstall grub. You must not shut down the system during this process or otherwise it could end up unbootable.

To increase the root partition "to the left" is not possible when running the system (which means root partition is mounted). You only can do that from a system running from another partition (or external drive, maybe life disk etc.)

To avoid this, you may create a new partition and filesystem in the empty space, mount that somewhere (say /data) and then eventually create softlinks to increase existing space (e.g., `ln -s /data/music ~/music` will give you additional room below your home directory).